# Build a list if condition is met in one of several ranges on other tabs

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a script that builds a list for each subject in a row based on whether or not that subject appears within a specific year range within each tab.

Here is a sample version of my data for reference: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fRhsIAeQd2qDIWILhvhnoTr1Po009RljdjrL9TYwncI/edit#gid=0.

I manually filled in some of the rows column B on the "History" tab, but this is what I want the script to produce (the cells highlighted red).

My best idea so far is to create an object for all of the names and use a for loop to go through each name... then to create separate objects for each role and year, and loop through those with a conditional check to search for the name. If the name appears in that year range, perhaps I can push some text to a new object?

I started writing a script for this but quickly realized it's going to be really painful and inefficient. Any ideas for how I can do this more efficiently? My data goes back several years for hundreds of people so manual updating just isn't an option anymore!

Thanks!!

```
    function buildHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var names = historySheet.getRange(2, 1, historySheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  var pastMems = ss.getSheetByName("Past Members");
  var mems2015 = pastMems.getRange(3, 2, pastMems.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var mems2014 = pastMems.getRange(3, 5, pastMems.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    Logger.log(name);

    for (var j = 0; j < mems2015.length; j++) {
      if (mems2015[j] == name) {
        Logger.log("Mem in 2015");
      } else if (mems2014[j] == name) {
        Logger.log("Mem in 2014");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Are you open to restructuring how your data is stored?  Is this a shared spreadsheet?  Even though your current situation is not optimal, and the code might need to be adjusted every year, it might be less work to write the code, than convert to a database, or restructure everything.  I don't think the amount of data that you have should be a problem.

Comment: Yes, restructuring the data would be fine by me! It's shared, but only one person at a time really owns the compiling piece.

Comment: The main information is the person.  Everything is linked to the persons name.  I think the tricky part is that a person can probably be on different committees in different years.  You'd need start and ending dates for each committee associated with that person.  One of the main issues is always, "Is it worth it?".  The amount of work to make it "better", might be more than it's worth.   It depends.

Comment: Here is a link to a good explanation of some basic stuff to know when structuring your data.  [Relational Databases](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/knowing-just-enough-about-relational-databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would structure the code.  This example is incomplete.  I did not try to run it.  It's meant to show a basic strategy of how the program would flow, and how the data would be processed.  Again, the code is incomplete.  The code does have a way to dynamically determine the start column for each year in a sheet.  It shows how to associate a name, with that person's history.

```
var masterObject = {};
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function masterFunction() {
  initialPopulationOfMasterObject();
  processPastVolunteersSheet();
  processPastSponsersSheet();
  addDataToHistory();
};

function initialPopulationOfMasterObject() {
  var historySheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var names = historySheet.getRange(2, 1, historySheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var i=0;

  for (i=0;i<names.length;i+=1) {
    masterObject.thisPerson = names[i];
    masterObject.theirHistory = []; //array for list of this person's history
  };
};


function processPastVolunteersSheet() {
  var volunteersSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Past Volunteers");
  var numberOfYears = 3;
  var yrs = 0, thisYrsData=[], startColumn;
  var j=0, thisName="", thisYr="";

  for (yrs=0;yrs<numberOfYears;yrs+=1) {
    if (yrs=0) {
      startColumn = 1;
      thisYr = volunteersSheet.getRange(1, startColumn, 1,1).getValue();
    } else {
      startColumn = yrs*3;
      thisYr = volunteersSheet.getRange(1, startColumn, 1,1).getValue();
    };
    thisYrsData=volunteersSheet.getRange(2, startColumn, volunteersSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    for (j=0;j<thisYrsData;j+=1) {
      masterObject[thisName].push("Volunteer (" + thisYr);
    };
  };
};
```